# OpenMPI - same rank on different procs

Tags: c, operating-system, openmpi

I've been working a bit with OpenMPI, and I'm not getting the expected behavior when requiring ranks from my procs.

I have a simple C program that is supposed to print each proc's rank :

*minimal.c :*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int procs;
    unsigned int self;
    MPI_Comm com;

    /* MPI ini */
    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
    com = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    MPI_Comm_size (com, &procs);
    MPI_Comm_rank (com, &self);

    printf("My rank is %d\n", self);

    /* MPI Finalize */
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

which I compile with :

```
mpicc minimal.c -o minimal
```

---

Now, if I run the following command on my own computer :

```
mpirun -np 2 minimal
```

I get the following trace :

> ```
> $ mpirun -np 2 minimal
> My rank is 0
> My rank is 0
> ```

which I found quite disconcerting.

---

So, I kept on digging the mpirun manual, and ended up printing additional infos with *-display-devel-map* and *-report-bindings*, and this the trace I got :

> ```
> $ mpirun -np 2 -display-devel-map -report-bindings minimal
>  Data for JOB [53858,1] offset 0
>
>  Mapper requested: NULL  Last mapper: round_robin  Mapping policy: BYCORE  Ranking policy: SLOT
>  Binding policy: CORE:IF-SUPPORTED  Cpu set: NULL  PPR: NULL  Cpus-per-rank: 1
>   Num new daemons: 0  New daemon starting vpid INVALID
>   Num nodes: 1
>
>  Data for node: UX31A     Launch id: -1   State: 2
>   Daemon: [[53858,0],0]   Daemon launched: True
>   Num slots: 2    Slots in use: 2 Oversubscribed: FALSE
>   Num slots allocated: 2  Max slots: 0
>   Username on node: NULL
>   Num procs: 2    Next node_rank: 2
>   Data for proc: [[53858,1],0]
>       Pid: 0  Local rank: 0   Node rank: 0    App rank: 0
>       State: INITIALIZED  App_context: 0
>       Locale: [BB/..]
>       Binding: [BB/..]
>   Data for proc: [[53858,1],1]
>       Pid: 0  Local rank: 1   Node rank: 1    App rank: 1
>       State: INITIALIZED  App_context: 0
>       Locale: [../BB]
>       Binding: [../BB]
> [UX31A:04861] MCW rank 1 bound to socket 0[core 1[hwt 0-1]]: [../BB]
> [UX31A:04861] MCW rank 0 bound to socket 0[core 0[hwt 0-1]]: [BB/..]
> My rank is 0
> My rank is 0
> ```

which left me puzzled.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and the OpenMPI packages from the apt repos. My computer is an Asus UX31a.

I'd be very grateful if someone could give me some insight on what is happening here.

Thank you !

Comment: That typically occurs when you use `mpirun` from `Open MPI` but your app uses the libs from `mpich`. Try `which mpirun` and `mpirun -np 2 ldd minimal` to double check that. And try `mpirun -np 2 ./minimal` too.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks

Comment: You were right @GillesGouaillardet , thanks a lot !

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet : Unfortunately, this is not always the cause. I get this problem on a machine that has _only_ `OpenMPI` installed. I checked and double-checked, there is only one version. The problem seems to be related to `CMake` and `Boost.MPI`, I am still investigating.

Comment: @LaryxDecidua I also had this problem with a `CMake` project using `OpenMPI`, with `OpenMPI` as the only mpi library installed. I deleted my build folder and created a new build folder and the problem disappeared. I was not using `Boost.MPI`, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was going on thanks to Gilles Gouaillardet !

Turns out I had `mpich` libs installed along with `openmpi` bins !

---

Here's what I did :

1. Check which library was used inside my binary :

   `$ ldd minimal
       ...
       libmpich.so.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.12
       ...`

   `$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.12
       libmpich12:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpich.so.12.1.0`
2. Check which package provided my `mpicc` and `mpirun` binaries :

   `$ which mpirun
       /usr/bin/mpirun`

   `$ dpkg -S mpirun
       openmpi-bin: /usr/bin/mpirun.openmpi
       ...`
3. I removed the `mpich` packages I had installed

   `sudo apt-get remove libmpich12 libmpich-dev`
4. I installed the `openmpi` libraries I needed

   `sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev`

---

I compiled again once this was done :

```
$ mpicc minimal.c -o minimal
$ mpirun -np 2 minimal
My rank is 0
My rank is 1
```

Hurray !